# Center a Group of Objects

Tags: c#, language-agnostic, unity-game-engine, centering

NOTE: I'm attempting to do this in Unity in C#, but the answer should be an algorithm that would work on any language unless there's a Unity-specific or C#-specific way to do it.

I am attempting to center a group of different objects. Given a number of objects which we'll call `numObjects`, the amount of space between each object which we'll call `space`, and the size of the screen, which we'll call `Screen.width` and `Screen.height`, I need to know the x at which the first object should be set. From there, I'd just add `space` then the next object. In the end, the space between the left edge of the first object and the left edge of the screen would be the same as the space between the right edge of the last object and the right edge of the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be mistaken in what you're trying to do, but assuming you want to space objects equally horizontally across a screen, this would simply require some elementary mathematics:

```
int space = Screen.width / (numObjects+1);
```

---

Edit in response to clarification (again its just simple math):

```
// determine the total width of the block of objects

totalWidthOfObjects = numObjects * widthOfEachObject
totalWidthOfSpacesBetweenObjects = (numObjects-1) * space
totalWidth = totalWidthOfObjects + totalWidthOfSpacesBetweenObjects

offsetFromLeft = (Screen.width - totalWidth) / 2
```

Note that this assumes each Object has the same width, otherwise it's a little bit more complex.

Comment: I don't want to space the objects evenly, I want to center the objects. Consider this: `OSOSOSOS`. O represents an object and S represents a space. I want to center that on the screen so it would look like this: `|     OSOSOSOS     |`. In that example, there are 5 spaces on either side so it's centered.